# How to recode values in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, recode

I have the following data, where I have calculated the `tercile` for each value in `x`:

```
dc <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9))
dc$tercile <- fabricatr::split_quantile(dc$x, 3)

x tercile
1       1
2       1
5       2
6       2
8       3
9       3
```

I want to reflect the ranges in `x` for each `tercile`. The desired output:

```
x       tercile
1    period 1-2
2    period 1-2
5    period 5-6
6    period 5-6
8    period 8-9
9    period 8-9
```

A `tidyverse` solution is preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf()` or `paste()` by groups of `tercile`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dc %>%
  mutate(range = sprintf("period %d-%d", min(x), max(x)),
         .by = tercile)

#   x tercile      range
# 1 1       1 period 1-2
# 2 2       1 period 1-2
# 3 5       2 period 5-6
# 4 6       2 period 5-6
# 5 8       3 period 8-9
# 6 9       3 period 8-9
```

Comment: This works when I use `group_by(tercile)` instead of `.by = tercile`. Any idea why? And what is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: @CloftX `.by = tercile` is a new feature after `dplyr v1.1.0`. It's a shortcut of `df %>% group_by(tercile) %>% mutate(...) %>% ungroup()`. You need to update `dplyr` version to activate it.